# Mock an object with a constructor - Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

How do I mock an object with a constructor using Rhino Mocks?

For example how would this object be mocked...

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private IBar bar;
    public Foo (IBar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar
    }

    public DoSomeThingAwesome()
    {
       //awesomeness happens here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't mock `Foo` - you mock `IFoo`. To test `Foo` itself, you mock `IBar` and pass the mock into the constructor.

You should try to avoid having things which rely on `IFoo` explicitly constructing instances of `Foo`: they should either be given a factory if `IFoo` somehow, or have an `IFoo` explicitly passed to them.

Comment: Well it preety obvious now that you said it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var myIFoo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
```

you can check awesomeness happened via

```
myIFoo.AssertWasCalled(f => f.DoSomethingAwesome());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since I used Rhino but I believe you can do:

`mockRespository.StrictMock<Foo>( ibarVariable )`

However it won't really work unless all of Foo's members are virtual.